# How to pass a variable to a function in Python

Tags: string, python-3.7

I am a newbie, and my first post, so please excuse for any protocol violations or novice coding mistakes :)

Working with Python 3.7 code.

Assignment: Find a character in a string and add a series of characters before the found character. The character occurs multiple times in the string.
Approach:

Loaded string into a variable:

Passed this variable and the character to a function that returns the indices of the character, if the character is found in the variable.

Iterate through the indices to add the series of characters

```
def find_indices_of(char, in_string):
    index = -1
    print(index)
    while True:
        index = in_string.find(char, index + 1)
        if index == -1:
            break
        yield index
var1 = "abcabcabc"
for i in find_indices_of('b', var1):
        var1 = var1[:i] + 'XY' + var1[i:]
```

Problem: For the first iteration of the loop when the function call happens for the first time, the function is given the variable(var1) as a constant and is returning a constant set of indices. But the logic in the iteration is adding a series of characters to the variable. This updated variable is not passed to the function every time the function is called. As a result, the index of the character is not updated, hence the further iterations of the loop are working with the old index values. This is resulting in the series of characters added at the undesired indexes.

Desired Output:
aXYZbcaXYZbcaXYZbc

Actual Output:

aXYZbXYZcXYZabcabc

I am struggling to submit the updated variable as an argument to the function:find_indices_of to get the right indices. I also need the function to omit the prior occurrences of the char before returning the updated indices. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy: May you share that with me please?

Answer (score 0):

Here what you are doing that when **find_indices_of(char, in_string)** function is called
it return the list of all indexes. When you iterate on it and update the value of var1 so it is obvious that after first iteration the index of second **'b'** will be changed. it will not b same as **find_indices_of** function had return because you are adding some characters before first occurance of **'b'** so the second **'b'** will be shifted to higher index but in the list it have previous position so simply just iterate on a list in **reverse order** it will not change the position of other character.

```
for i in reversed(find_indices_of('b', var1)):
        var1 = var1[:i] + 'XY' + var1[i:]
```

Here is the basic implementation of your reqiured logic

```
def find(char, in_string):
    return [i for i, c in enumerate(in_string) if c == char]

var1 = "abcabcabc"
all_index = find('b',var1)
for i in reversed(all_index):
    var1 = var1[:i] + 'XYZ' + var1[i:]
print(var1)
```

The Output will look like this

```
 desired Output:aXYZbcaXYZbcaXYZbc 
 Actual Output: aXYZbcaXYZbcaXYZbc
```